# SQL Server 2008 : Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create a database using SQL Server 2008. I have my sql query to create it.
But everytime I want to execute it, I get this error message :
"Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed."

This is the part of the query where the problem is :

```
alter table PRODUIT add constraint ID_PRODUIT_CHK
     check(exists(select * from PRODUCTION
                  where PRODUCTION.IdProduit = IdProduit));
```

There is something wrong with the "check" but I don't know what.
Can you help me ?

Comment: It's not clear from what you're showing why a FOREIGN KEY constraint wouldn't be a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

A check constraint is only allowed to make assertions about the values of columns in the row. It's not allowed to reference other rows within the same table, let alone other tables.

There are some possible workarounds - as I say in my comment, it looks like you're trying to create a foreign key constraint. There are some fudges that may also work (by placing logic in a user defined function), but these usually have edge cases where the check will work during the initial insert/update, but can be violated later.

We'd need to understand your problem more clearly to suggest a workable solution. What are you trying to achieve. If it's *not* a foreign key constraint, what features of foreign key constraints don't work in your situation?

Comment: +1: Check constraints do support user defined functions, but I agree that the example provided is meant to be a foreign key constraint.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I don't believe that allowing you to make assertions against other tables/rows was explicitly thought about when allowing UDFs to be called by CHECK constraints - it's more a "happy" accident, like "TOP 100 PERCENT" and "ORDER BY" were in pre-2005 views. If they actually wanted to support such functionality, I'd expect them to add ANSI standard `ASSERTION`.